# How to iterate in a range determined by TWO variables?

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have a code:

```
echo "the range's starting number:"
read -r a #it was 10
echo "the range's ending number:"
read -r b #it was 20
for (( c=$a; c<=$b; c++ ))
do
echo $c
done
```

Question: what is the working syntax? I found a similar question where c=1; c<=$b; c++ worked. I want to iterate between $a (example $a=10) and $b (example $b=20) and not between 1 and $b=20. Thanks for the help. (the output is blank here, the expected output was:
10
11
12
..
20
I tried my code, also closed terminal and started a new one because of possible caching issues, but there was still a blank output.
**Update: in the comments accdias's answer was working. With for ((c=a; c<=b; c++)) i got the expected output. Thanks all for the help and comments!**

Comment: `for ((c=a; c<=b; c++))` will do the trick.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: have you tried running your code? if you replace `#command` with `echo "${c}"`, what do you get? if you don't get the desired result then update the question with the (wrong) output generated and the (correct) expected output; also update the question with the values of `a` and `b` that you state generates 'output is blank here'

Comment: markp-fuso thanks, i edit it now..

Comment: Cyrus: yes, it was an echo in my own code. I accidentally pasted #command here instead but i just edited it. Although the problem was that is used $ in for loop instead of just typing c=a; and so on.. :)

Comment: It makes no difference with `bash` whether you use `for (( c=$a; c<=$b; c++ ))` or `for (( c=a; c<=b; c++ ))`.

Answer (score 0):

I took @accdias's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71719012/how-to-iterate-in-a-range-determined-by-two-variables#comment126746089_71719012) and figured I would just drop it here as an answer for easy reference:

```sh
START=12
END=24
for ((i=START; i<=END; i++)); do
  echo $i
done
```